# how to get rid of Â character in html form

Tags: java, mysql, html, css, character-encoding

My input tag started to go crazy... I have html form for input to database and it was working ok... In one moment it started to input me "Â" before typed text to database and to view...

If it is of importance project is in Java, and data is in MySQL.

the code is same as for 100 other forms that I have in project I checked 10 times.

the part that is making mistake is :

```
<tr>
  <td><label for="agr_notes">Nota</label></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="agr_notes" id="agr_notes" class="text ui-widget-content 
       ui-corner-all"/></td>
</tr>
```

And for example instead of input ASD i get Â ASD in database and on screen.

Comment: from the html that renders the input tag you will not find any error. Your error lies somewhere on clientside between taking over the val and writing to database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the encoding type of the table in which you store the data in your database. Maybe it is not the same as all other tables. Since the characters appear after inserting values and all other forms are working, the problem must be around encoding or string format.

I suggest checking the encoding in database.

Comment: Unexpected Â characters are a pretty sure sign of encoding gone wrong, typically, of UTF-8 encoded data being treated as windows-1252 or iso-8859-1. Minimally, a functional URL should be provided. (Code snippets are not enough, since encodings are set in HTTP headers primarily.)

Answer (score 0):

ok I added in Java code where I create new import to class from form just one new local variable that call getter for that field that gives me String value and do substring method of first char.
It works fine to me. I tryed to find setting for characters but it is boring job :).

```
String s = form.getNotes().substring(2);
```

and after instead calling:

```
newImport.setNotes(form.getNotes());
```

I typed:

```
newImport.setNotes(s);
```

But I manage to do another thing everytime when I enter in edit mode it delete me 2 chars.

I fixwd and code is this:

```
String notes;
  String removeFirst = f.getAgr_notes();
  if(removeFirst.startsWith("Â")){
   notes=removeFirst.substring(2);

  } else {notes=removeFirst;}
```

at the end you need to call notes string.

Comment: That's not a good solution, please think of other developers, that possibly have to read your code in the future... you should really try to solve the problem. Could you tell me, how your HTML page is encoded? Is it UTF-8, is it only declared as UTF-8 in the meta tags, or is the file stored in the UTF-8 file format? A link would be helpful.

Comment: yes whole project is declared in config files as UTF-8. I even tryed to put another meta tag to that page but it make this again. I have a lot of work and small time so must try to find faster solution to put project in use and then i will test and solve bugs.